# Switching on type with a generic return type

Tags: c#, generics, c#-7.0

I'm working on making EF easier to unit test by writing some helpers that will make properties for me.  I have a couple of backing fields

```
private Mock<DbSet<Workflow>> mockedWorkFlows;
private Mock<DbSet<WorkflowError>> mockedWorkFlowErrors;
```

And I want a generic function to be able to return me the correct backing field with the following function

```
public Mock<DbSet<T>> Mocked<T>(T t) where T : class
{
   if ( (object)t is Workflow)
   {
       return mockedWorkFlows; //cannot Workflow to T
    }
}
```

There are several private backing fields which I want to be returned based on the type passed it.

However, even if I add a class constraint of `Workflow`, I get the same error.

I also tried switching on `t's` type but no luck there either.  The types of the several backing fields do not share a common ancestor, other than object.  Is what I'm trying to do possible?

Comment: I don't see what the point of this method would be. Creating a mock takes 1 line of code and if you want to setup the mock you have to individually setup every mock anyway, so why don't you just create a factory for mocks of certain types.

Comment: It's more than one line of code to mock an IDbSet<T> from your EF context.  I have a fluent interface for assigning the data, but you have to expose the backing field somewhere because when you spy that's what is actually getting called.  I just want a smaller API instead of having a WorkflowsMocked, WorkflowErrorsMocked, etc. for all of the IDbSet properties of the context .

Comment: Instead of mocking the `DbSet`, have you considered mocking the `SqlConnection` instead, for example, using the Effort framework?   https://github.com/tamasflamich/effort

Comment: @BenCottrell no, I haven't seen Effort, but as far as the tests are concerned there is no database, any EF calls are mocked anyway.  This problem really isn't directly related to EF or mocking at all.  I just want to have a return type depend on a type parameter to a generic function essentially.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understand your intention correctly - you can do it like this:

```
// no need to pass instance of T - why?
public Mock<DbSet<T>> Mocked<T>() where T : class
{
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(Workflow)) {
        // first cast to object, then to return type to avoid compile error
        // compiler does not know mockedWorkFlows is Mock<DbSet<T>>, but you
        // know it already, because you checked type 'T'
        return (Mock<DbSet<T>>) (object) mockedWorkFlows; //cannot Workflow to T
    }
    // etc
    return null;
}
```

Whether it is good idea or not is a different story.

Comment: this is what I was looking for.  I was trying to use the sleekness of the switch on type for C#7, but this is ultimately what I was looking for (although I'm getting a different error now! :))

Answer (score 11):

It is possible to seriously abuse C#7's `switch` to achieve what you want by switching on an unrelated value and using the `var` pattern with `when` guards:

```
public Mock<DbSet<T>> Mocked<T>() where T : class
{
    switch(true)
    {
        case var _ when typeof(T) == typeof(Workflow):
            return ...
        case var _ when typeof(T) == typeof(WorkflowError):
            return ...
        default:
            return null;
    }
}
```

Being able to match on types in `switch` statements is a very common request. There are proposals for improvements to C# on the official language repo on github (see [Proposal: switch on System.Type](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/356) and p[Proposal: Pattern match via generic constraint](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/905)). As and when more pattern matching functionality is added to C# ([currently, set for "a 7.X release"](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/milestone/7)), we may get nicer syntax for this functionality.