# Can I use pattern matching for code like this (on generic types)

Tags: c#, generics, pattern-matching, c#-7.0

I want use pattern matching to replace multiple `if` statements as shown below in method `Select<T>()`. I want to use the `switch()` statement on `typeof(T)`.

```
static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var doc = new Document();
        IWire select = doc.Select<IWire>();
    }

    public static T Select<T>(this Document document) where T : class, IGeneric
    {
        var t = typeof(T);
        if (t.IsAssignableTo(typeof(IWire)))
        {
            return document.SelectEntity(EntityType.Wire) as T;
        }
        if (t.IsAssignableTo(typeof(ISolid)))
        {
            return document.SelectEntity(EntityType.Solid) as T;
        }
        if (t.IsAssignableTo(typeof(ISurface)))
        {
            return document.SelectEntity(EntityType.Surface) as T;
        }
        // imagine a lot of if statements here
        return null;
    }
}

public enum EntityType
{
    Wire,
    Surface,
    Solid
}

public interface IGeneric
{
}

public interface IWire : IGeneric
{
}
public interface ISurface : IGeneric
{
}
public interface ISolid : IGeneric
{
}

public class Document
{
    public IGeneric SelectEntity(EntityType entity)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

All the examples I have seen use an *instance* in the `switch(thing)` statement and code like the following is obviously wrong

```
switch(typeof(T))
{
    case // what here?
}
```

Comment: Can you share the rest of code and minimal reproducible sample? Actually, type pattern matching were added in c# 7

Comment: But type pattern matching is working with value of particular type, `T` in your case, not with type itself

Comment: Seems related: [Switching on type with a generic return type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46756172/3744182).

Comment: There are also two related GitHub threads, for [switch on System.Type](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/356) and [pattern match via generic constraint](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/905)

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski - I made a mcve to show the issue.

Comment: Please, note that the exact type matching and `IsAssignableFrom` isn't the same actually

Comment: Actually, does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46769048/3744182) to [Switching on type with a generic return type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46756172/3744182) fully answer your question?

Comment: In my case the instances come from an API with only interfaces exposed. So I don't know what the concrete types are, just the interfaces. Hence the need for `.IsAssignableFrom()`.

Comment: Seems like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46769048/3744182) could be tweaked to do `case var _ when t.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(IWire)):`

Comment: @dbc IMO, the OP gets almost the same stuff. It seems, that `if` conditions look most readable here, because of _IsAssignableFrom_

Comment: @dbc - technically this is exactly what I am asking for, although it seems _hacky_ and maybe marginally a little cleaner than the original code.

Comment: @ja72 - right, the answer states that a pretty way to do this isn't currently implemented, points to some open enhancement threads, and gives a hacky workaround.  Your current code looks better than the workaround IMHO.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So the answer based on the comments is that `C#` can't do this yet (it is proposed [here](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/905) and [here](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/356)).

But there is a hack, illustrated by in https://stackoverflow.com/a/46769048/380384, although not an exact duplicate.

The solution I could use is as follows (thanks @dbc for pointing me in the right direction).

```
public static T Select<T>(this Document document) where T : class, IGeneric
{
    var t = typeof(T);
    switch (true)
    {
        case var _ when t.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(IWire)):
            return document.SelectEntity(EntityType.Wire) as T;

        case var _ when t.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(ISurface)):
            return document.SelectEntity(EntityType.Surface) as T;

        case var _ when t.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(ISolid)):
            return document.SelectEntity(EntityType.Solid) as T;

        default:
            return null;
    }

}
```

But as far as readability and design intent, it might really be an improvement over the sequence of `if` statements.