# How to compare generic types usnig c# language?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, string-comparison

I'm making a game in Unity and I'm using a sort of factory pattern where I need to create a Tile object of a specific type, and I'm not sure how to compare types in C#.

This is my code:

```
public T SpawnTile<T>(Vector3 startPosition) where T : Tile

{

    Tile t;

    if(T == MountainTile) // This line

    {

        t = new MountainTile();

    }

    if (T == WaterTile) // And this line

    {

        t = new WaterTile();

    }

    return (T)t;

}
```

I searched everywhere and all I found was the usage of obj is Type, but in my case I want to compare the generic type T.

I also tried `Types.Equals(T, WaterTile)` but it didn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: You might want to use the `new` constraint.

Comment: Add the `new` constraint and you can do `return new T();`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I use pattern matching for code like this (on generic types)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59687295/can-i-use-pattern-matching-for-code-like-this-on-generic-types)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do this work for you?

```
Tile t;
var type = T as Type
switch (type)
{
    case Type _ when type == typeof(MountainTile):
         t = new MountainTile();
        break;

    case Type _ when type == typeof(WaterTile):
        t = new WaterTile();
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Of course, you can compare them by using **typeof** keyword:

```
public T SpawnTile<T>(Vector3 startPosition) where T : Tile
{

    T t;

    if(typeof(T) == typeof(MountainTile)) // This line
    {

       t = new MountainTile();

    }

    if (typeof(T) == typeof(WaterTile)) // And this line
    {

       t = new WaterTile();

    }

    return t;

}
```

But, as was mentioned in comments it's better to use **new** constraint if possible:

```
public T SpawnTile<T>(Vector3 startPosition) where T : Tile, new()
{
    T t = new T();

    // Other actions...

    return t;
}
```