# C# Pattern matching on type parameter Itself

Tags: c#

I have to write this code, with a switch on strings to check for typeof(T):

```
public bool ContainsKey<T>(Guid id)
    {
        string ip = httpContext.HttpContext.Connection?.RemoteIpAddress.ToString();                        
        switch (GetLastPartOfClassService<T>())
        {
            case "Cart":
                return Carts.ContainsKey((ip, id));
            case "IsAuthenticatedModel":
                return Auths.ContainsKey((ip, id));
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }
  
    public string GetLastPartOfClassService<T>()
    {
        string fullClass = typeof(T).ToString();
        return fullClass.Substring(fullClass.LastIndexOf('.') + 1);
    }
```

There is no parameter value to use for pattern matching so I used a switch for checking strings, How to replace this with a strongly typed pattern matching. meaning, using `Cart` instead of `"Cart"`?

Comment: Not clear why you don't just use `if (typeof(T) == typeof(Cart))`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46769048